# How to use React without NPM's "require"?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs

Currently I am using React on Rails application (using `react-rails` library) and I wish to use some third party React components.

How to use third party component without adding dependency to RequireJS, Webpack, or Browserify? To be more specific, how can I do the following command in client side JS without depending on those library?

`var Select = require('react-select')`

The project is currently using Rails asset pipeline heavily and I believe getting rid of it is too expensive. The assets are pulled by `rails-assets`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the package/component is available through [Bower](http://bower.io/) you can rely on [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/). Rails assets works as bridge between bower the assets pipeline allowing you to add non-gem dependencies to the pipeline.

In the specific case your mention just add the following:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-react-select'
end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require react-select
```